# Does SE track previous website access?

Tags: support, users, privacy, tracking

I am wondering if math.stackexchange.com tracks or otherwise has a record of specific user-initiated access to the site, from a certain device at a specific time and date.

Comment: Moderators can access some of the information you ask in your first question.

Comment: To what end are you wondering such things?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You also need to focus on one specific question.

Comment: Why are you asking specifically about Math.SE?

Comment: While the motive for asking might be shady and unclear, the question itself is clear enough, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9):

I am not an employee, but here's what I've determined as a user and Moderator:

**Yes**, both logged in and non-logged in users are subject to tracking in some form.

---

> [Does SE have] a record of specific user-initiated access to the site...

**Yes**. Last activity is presented on all user accounts as a text description, eg. "Last Seen: Last week". A user's actions are also visible on their [Activity Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity). This is publicly viewable information.

Furthermore, a historical record of a user's site access is kept, but is private/only accessible by the logged in user, the site moderators, and some (but not all) Stack Exchange employees. A logged in user can view their account history by visiting their [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current), and clicking on the "Visited X days, Y consecutive" text along the top. This will present a calendar view with marked days that indicate activity on that day.

> ...from a certain device at a specific time and date.

**Yes**, according to the Privacy Policy, device/browser information is also kept:

> #### Device and browser information received automatically
>
> When you visit the Network or use our Apps, Stack Overflow automatically receives and records information from your browser or mobile device, such as your Internet Protocol (IP) address or unique device identifier. Cookies and data about which pages you visit on our Network allow us to operate and optimize the Products and Services we provide to you. This information is stored in secure logs and is collected automatically.
>
> We may combine this browser information with other information we collect about you. This information is used to keep the Products and Services secure, to analyze and understand how our Products and Services are used, optimize such usage, provide advertising across the Network as well as certain Products and Services to personalize your experience, and to help connect you with potential job opportunities in the case of our recruiting Products and Services.

This can be combined with other activity data as mentioned above, which would include time and date actions

---

> Does Stack Exchange distinguish between deliberate user-initiated access to the site and activity that is simply due to background processes occurring on a device?

As far as I am aware, Stack Exchange only tracks user-initiated actions, which can include page loads and any site actions (voting, commenting, asking/answering, flagging, clicking on links etc). I am not aware of any background processes that - when left running - would result in tracking, except perhaps any adverts that are displayed.

---

For an in-depth overview of the Privacy implications of viewing the Stack Exchange network, you should check out the Privacy Policy, specifically the section: [WHAT INFORMATION DO WE COLLECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy#info-we-collect).

For information about cookies stored on your computer (and what control you have over them), you should also look at the [Cookie Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy)